# Passwordless ssh from Ubuntu 22.04 to RHEL5

Tags: ssh

I've never had an issue with passwordless ssh connections by copying the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` on the other sever until now.

I want to migrate data from an old RHEL5 server to a new Ubuntu 22.04 server which takes several hours and requires passwordless `ssh` at various times during the migration script. I initially had issues with "no matching host key type found" and "no matching key exchange method found" but overcame these with various options. I have used the following...

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss root@<old_server>
```

But still get prompted for a password even though the contents of `id_rsa.pub` have been added to `authorized_keys`.

The `id_rsa.pub` file was created using  `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

The `ssh` has to be initiated on the new Ubuntu server to 'pull' data from the old server due to the complexity of the migration script.

I know RHEL5 is very old and maybe Ubuntu 22.04 has closed this sort of access due to the age of RHEL5.

Has anyone managed to overcome this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on `old_server`  for `PubkeyAuthentication`, must be `yes` and not commented. (if you change something, restart `sshd`. If that is not the issue, please run your `ssh` command with `-v` option and copy the output to your question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you also confirm the pull path to `authorized_keys` on the old server?